# Caching PHP Classes with Memcache

Tags: php, memcached

I am adding memcache into my site and the problem I am having is that I am caching the object so its easy to use inside other objects or pages. The problem is that I am caching the object when I load it, so if I made a change to a variable in the object, its not passed onto the other pages. Am I missing something or do I really have to save the cached object after all processing?

```
// ON THE PAGE I FIRST CALL
$objState = $gb->objCache->State('1');
echo "Name:" . $objState->get_Name() . "<br>";
$objState->set_Name('New Name');

// ON ANOTHER PAGE I CALL IT AGAIN
$objState = $gb->objCache->State('1');
echo "Name:" . $objState->get_Name() . "<br>";
$objState->set_Name('New Name 2');

// THE FUNCTION THAT I CALL TO GET THE STATE CLASS/OBJECT
function State($id, $reload=false) {
  $objState = null;

  $cached = false;
  if (is_object($this->gb->memcache))
    $cached = $this->gb->memcache->get('objState_' . $id . '_' .  getCompanyUniqueID());
  if ($cached !== FALSE && is_object($cached) && !$reload) {
    $objState = $cached;
  } else    {               
        $objState = new State($id);

      // Store generated XML for 5 minutes (300 seconds)
    if (is_object($this->gb->memcache))
        $this->gb->memcache->set('objState_' . $id . '_' .  getCompanyUniqueID(), $objState, 0, 300); // Don't worry about third argument, it controls compression
    }

  return $objState;
}
```

Comment: You have to write any changes to memcache if you want it to persist on memcache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memcached stores the data as a serialized entity so any changes will need to be committed. You could try writing an object to commit your data when the script finishes executing with the PHP register_shutdown function.